# htaccess redirect and remove filename

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My redirect rules are preserving the filename and resulting in 404 errors.

The root rules I have are:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then an example of a redirect is:

```
Redirect 301 /section-1/services.php http://www.domain.com/section-2/
```

But when tested it results in:

http://www.domain.com/section-2/services.php

I've looked everywhere for this specific issue and can't find the answer. It feels like it must be quite simple but just can't get anything to work.

Any help would be really great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try,

That redirect should work. However you can try this.

Remove this line or comment it out.

```
Redirect 301 /section-1/services.php http://www.domain.com/section-2/
```

And replace it with this.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^section-1/services.php$ /section-2/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.

It kind of works but it now creates the URL:

http://www.domain.com/services/services/

I just need it to have the one folder:

http://www.domain.com/services/

Comment: Works fine for me. What are your other htaccess rules?

Comment: did you take this out `Redirect 301 /section/services.php http://www.domain.com/services/`?

Comment: No that's still in along with maybe 100 similar redirects.

I've got the following now in the head:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+).php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/ [R=301,L]

Comment: Sorry it doesn't paste the code in neatly in comments

Comment: Are all your redirects from php files to non php files? You might be able to consolidate that using rewrite instead of having 100 redirects to manage.

Comment: Is this a live site? If not remove all the other rules below those two you just pasted, then test it just to eliminate something else conflicting, you can put them back later. Clear your browser cache too before testing it again.

Comment: The redirects are from PHP files to a folder structure but the folder names are not the same as the PHP filenames so I can't create a consolidated rewrite rule. I'll try cutting down the redirects to see if there is a conflict as you say.

Comment: It doesn't have to be one rewrite rule but it's probably better than all those individual ones. But that is another question. :)

Comment: It is still going from /section-1/services.php to /section/services/ then to /section-2/services/ rather than just /section-2/

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do more than you initially stated with the redirects. The code I gave you works for the example you provided. Is this htaccess in your root directory or the section folder? That matters. Also Update your question with the correct actual redirect you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry I realise I didn't make it clearer as to the full redirect going on. I've updated the question to explain the URL changes more accurately. The htaccess file is at the site root.